# Rust geojson : expected enum found reference

Tags: rust

very new to Rust, I am literally copying and pasting the example from this page https://docs.rs/geojson/0.19.0/geojson/enum.Value.html#conversion-from-geo_types, which is:

```
let point = geo_types::Point::new(2., 9.);
assert_eq!(
geojson::Value::from(&point),
geojson::Value::Point(vec![2., 9.]),
);
```

I get the following error:

```
let point = geo_types::Point::new(2., 9.);

mismatched types

note:   expected enum `geojson::Value`
  found reference `&geo_types::Point<{float}>`rustc(E0308)
```

My cargo.toml file looks like this :

```
[dependencies]
polyline = "0.8.0"
geo-types = "0.6.0"
geojson = "0.19.0"
```

Could you help me, I looked at the source code, the ::from is behind a feature geo_types, but since I imported the library I thought it would work ... Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the `geo-types` feature in `geojson`

```
[dependencies]
polyline = "0.8.0"
geo-types = "0.6.0"
geojson = { version = "0.19.0", features = ["geo-types"] }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried adding a [features] section with geo-types = [] but the compiler did not like it, thanks for helping me getting this.

Comment: The `[features]` table in your Cargo.toml is for defining features in _your project_. I recommend this reference whenever you're not sure about the Cargo.toml format: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html